# How to create Windows Phone 8 app package for windows store using VS Express 2012 for windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, package, windows-store-apps, creation

We have developed a windows phone 8 app using VS express 2012 for windows phone. Everything works fine until viewing the app in emulator.

We want to package this app for the windows store. As from the MSDN and other sites VS Express 2012 for windows 8 does have an option to create the package for store from the menu "STORE->Create Package". Unfortunately the phone app developed says incompatible while trying to open in this VS.

Is there another way in which a package can be created from VS express 2012 for windows phone?

Any information on this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're hoping to publish a Windows Phone 8 app to the Windows Store (on Windows 8)?

Publishing to each store (phone/Windows) is a separate process, requiring different projects, and as you've seen, [different versions of Visual Studio Express 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714071%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Getthetools).

There's an helpful [Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 App Development Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714089%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for guidance on doing this, and a recent article by Doug Holland on ["Sharing Code between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Applications"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201744.aspx) that should help as well.